# Theming media inserts

Tags: theme-development, attachments, media

When I Insert media into my post or page it's rendered as a normal link.

Would it be possible to somehow theme links that point to e.g. PDF or other file types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be doing this with jQuery:

http://jsfiddle.net/pFyPz/

Comment: It seems to be the best/easiest solution.